# Is this JSON, How do I parse this JSON?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
{suggestion:[{query:"Cakung, Djakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:6,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e698b10568c13a1:0x400c5e82dd4c010",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:9938},{start:8,end:16,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",type:37},{start:18,end:40,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",type:545},{start:42,end:51,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:9938,confidence:0.016646922403780989},{query:"Churches",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:8,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x1000000000000000:0x225176c87865ce94",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:856337}]},operation:2,target_type:856337,confidence:0.0085971010172646231},{query:"Canada",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:6,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x4b0d03d337cc6ad9:0x9968b72aa2438fa5",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:33,confidence:0.0085105111169293587},{query:"California, United States",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:10,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x808fb9fe5f285e3d:0x8b5109a227086f55",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:545},{start:12,end:25,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742",type:33}]},operation:2,target_type:545,confidence:0.006658654709552795},{query:"Cafe",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:4,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x1000000000000000:0x848050558421ac48",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:856337}]},operation:2,target_type:856337,confidence:0.0058785606823066935},{query:"Colleges",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:8,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x1000000000000000:0xdb6190dc25a99356",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:856337}]},operation:2,target_type:856337,confidence:0.0053999922318009111},{query:"China",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:5,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x31508e64e5c642c1:0x951daa7c349f366f",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:33}]},operation:2,details:[{value:"中国",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:2,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x31508e64e5c642c1:0x951daa7c349f366f",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:33}]}}],target_type:33,confidence:0.0044838706757038835},{query:"Clubs",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:5,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x1000000000000000:0x3897b0017192e20d",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:856337}]},operation:2,target_type:856337,confidence:0.0039399659782221796},{query:"Chinese Restaurant",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:18,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x1000000000000000:0x60920a49a18e016a",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:856337}]},operation:2,target_type:856337,confidence:0.0039022718761534195},{query:"Cinema",interpretation:{term:[{start:0,end:6,feature_type:"",feature_id:"0x1000000000000000:0xb29dbbe5e89f763f",matched:1,target:1,term_start:0,term_end:1,type:856337}]},operation:2,target_type:856337,confidence:0.0037837480879625448}],probability_sum:[2.293141542524348e-06]}
```

Notice that dictionary pattern is like JSON but there is no quote in query:, etc. SBJSON fail because of this.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.json.org for more information on the JSON standard and parse engines for most programming languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not JSON

JSON should have the keys in quotation marks.

{"suggestion":[{"query"... etc.

Answer (score 0):

This was probally, as there are not quotes around query, just made to be used with JavaScript's eval, which is not great. You will have to either look for another reader or put the query in quotes.